# Given a integer n, divide into two integers' sum (a + b), possibility of getting a pair (a, b) without digit 0?

Tags: probability, algorithms

The question comes from a Leetcode coding problem. Given an integer $n$ ($n$ > 1), find a pair of integers $(a, b)$ (both $a$ and $b >= 1$) so that $a + b = n$. What is the probability $P$ of finding such a pair out of all sum pairs, where neither $a$ or $b$ contains digit $0$.

For example, for $n = 5$, all sum pairs are $(1, 4), (2, 3)$, and none of them contains $0$, so $P = 1$; for $n = 32$, all sum pairs are $(1, 31), (2,30), ...(16, 16)$, 16 in total, while only $(2, 30), (10, 22), (20, 12)$ contain digit $0$, so $P = 13 / 16 = 0.8125$.

If $P$ cannot be easily represented as the function of $n$, what is the tendency? I wrote a code:

```
function solve(N) {
    if (N < 2) throw new Error('Input must >= 2');
    const test0 = x => /0/.test(String(x));
    const ans = [0];
    for (let n = 2; n <= N; n++) {
        let good = 0;
        for (let a = 1; a <= (n >> 1); a++) {
            const b = n - a;
            if (!test0(a) && !test0(b)) { 
                good++;
//              console.log(`(${a}, ${b})`); 
            }
        }
        const p = good / (n >> 1);
        ans.push(p);
    }
}
```

It shows that $P$ decreases with the increasing of $N$, overall. Will it approaches to $0$ when N is infinity?
[graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Tr1e.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it will.  When $N$ has *lots* of digits it is likely that at least one will be zero.  It is similar for $a, N-a$.  Most numbers have the digits reasonably evenly distributed, so the chance of not having a zero is $.9^{\log_{10}N}$.  $a$ and $N-a$ might have one digit less, but rarely more, so their chance will be about the same.